# kodi unmet dependencies on new server install

Tags: server, kodi

So I am trying to install Kodi on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I could use some help

After running sudo apt-get update and adding the Kodi PPA Repository, i get the following errors after installing:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages may have unmet dependencies:

```
   Kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (>=.....final.obionic) but it is not going to be 
   installed

   Depends: kodi-bin (>=.....final.obionic.1) but it is not going to be 
   installed

   Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable
   Depends: python-bluez but it is not installable or
            python-lightblue but it is not installable

   Depends: libmad0 but it is not installable
            libass9,5,4 but it is not installable
            libnfs11,8,4,1 but it is not installable
            libbluray1 but it is not installable
            libblueray2 but it is not installable
            libaacs0 but it is not installable
            libcec4 but it is not installable

  Recommends: libvdpau1 but it is not going to be installed
              i965-va-driver but it is not installable
              libva-intel-vaapi-driver but it is not installable
              libva1 but it is not installable
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Please help! any suggestions? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Two options here:

1. ask PPA maintainers about the problem;
2. use [`kodi` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=kodi) from repository (bionic has 17.6):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe

   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:team-xbmc/ppa

   sudo apt-get install kodi
   ```

Official Kodi site [says that 17.6 Krypton is recommended version](https://kodi.tv/download/850):

> [image: Kodi 17.6 is recommended]

Comment: @CaseyCushing Please specify the address of PPA, we need to purge it before proceeding.

Comment: Hi @N0bert I am following this:https://github.com/OnceUponALoop/mini-kodi

Comment: Add Kodi PPA Repository

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa

Comment: Updated answer. You can continue with Kodi packages from official repository.

Comment: I seem to have been trying that all along...What is the exact command I should be using for that?

Comment: You should run all commands inside gray box (p. 2).

Comment: N0rbert When running sudo apt-get install ppa-purge, it returned Unable to locate package ppa-purge.

Comment: hey N0rbert as far as I understand it, the packages I need are not in the 18.04.1 release. I need to edit the /etc/apt/sources.liist correct? in the file currently, there is deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main, http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main, and http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main

Comment: Any idea what i should add/delete etc?

Comment: It seems that you do not have *universe* repository. Please execute `sudo add-apt-repository universe` before other commands.

Comment: The install started and seemed to complete, but when I try to launch it with just "kodi" i got: ERROR: unable to create GUI. Exiting.

Comment: + free(): invalid pointer arborted (core dumped)

Comment: @CaseyCushing Did you ever find a way to resolve the issue? I am currently running into the same error message